# Alternative to integer_sequence trick

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, c++17, variadic

I hate working with `std::integer_sequence`. Each time I want to write a function `foo` I have to write an another function `foo_impl` where the actual stuff is happening. Therefore I'm polluting the space with additional function and the code is kind of scattered around. I came up with an alternative and I would love to know your opinion.

---

Let's define `integral_sequence<N>`. Here we use the damned `std::integer_sequence` for the last time!

```
template <std::size_t... I>
constexpr auto integral_sequence_impl(std::index_sequence<I...>) {
  return std::make_tuple(std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I>{}...);
}

template <int N>
auto integral_sequence = integral_sequence_impl(std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
```

To demonstrate its use, lets redo [the example code](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence#Example) for `std::integral_sequence`:

```
// Convert array into a tuple
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
decltype(auto) a2t(const std::array<T, N> &a) {
  auto impl = [&](auto... I) { return std::make_tuple(a[I]...); };

  return std::apply(impl, integral_sequence<N>);
}

// pretty-print a tuple
template <class Ch, class Tr, class... Args>
decltype(auto) operator<<(std::basic_ostream<Ch, Tr> &os,
                          const std::tuple<Args...> & t) {

  auto impl = [&](auto... I) {
    ((os << (I == 0 ? "" : ", ") << std::get<I>(t)), ...);
  };

  os << "(";
  std::apply(impl, integral_sequence<sizeof...(Args)>);
  return os << ")";
}

int main() {
  std::array<int, 4> array = {1, 2, 3, 4};

  // convert an array into a tuple
  auto tuple = a2t(array);
  static_assert(
      std::is_same<decltype(tuple), std::tuple<int, int, int, int>>::value, "");

  // print it to cout
  std::cout << tuple << '\n';
}
```

The trick with `integral_sequence` is kind of the same as with `integer_sequence`. However, because it can be used with generic lambda you do not have to define an extra function, all code can be neatly together and it reduces visual clutter.

So what do you think? Are there any disadvantages?

The only problems I can see now is that it is only c++17 and `integral_sequence<400>` takes really long time to compile.

Answer (score 5):

Looks good to me! I mean, I'm not likely to convert to it because of its heavyweightness — you noted its use of `std::apply`, but it also pulls in all of `<tuple>` every time you use it, too. Also, it's arguably coincidental that your expressions `a[I]` and `std::get<I>(t)` work in this context, since what's actually happening in both cases is an *implicit conversion* from `std::integral_constant<size_t, K>` to `size_t`. In some contexts, the user might need to explicitly cast `int(I)` or whatever.

You could remove the `std::apply` dependency and simplify the user's job at the same time by writing a helper function `apply_to_sequence<N>(lambda)`, as in:

```
// Convert array into a tuple
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
auto a2t(const std::array<T, N>& a) {
  return apply_to_sequence<N>([&](auto... Is) {
      return std::make_tuple(a[Is]...);
  });
}
```

(Oh yeah, I think your use of `decltype(auto)` in this function was bogus and could result in dangling references. Certainly `auto` would be fine, so I recommend it.)

```
// pretty-print a tuple
template <class Ch, class Tr, class... Args>
auto& operator<<(std::basic_ostream<Ch, Tr>& os,
                          const std::tuple<Args...>& t)
{
  os << "(";
  apply_to_sequence<sizeof...(Args)>([&](auto... Is) {
    ((os << (Is == 0 ? "" : ", ") << std::get<Is>(t)), ...);
  });
  return os << ")";
}
```

Writing `apply_to_sequence` from scratch is left as an exercise for the reader, but the trivial C++17 implementation is just this:

```
template<size_t N, class F>
decltype(auto) apply_to_sequence(const F& fn) {
    return std::apply(fn, integral_sequence<N>);
}
```

Having hidden the implementation details `apply` and `integral_sequence` from the reader, we are now free — if we so desire — to replace them with things that are

- faster
- C++14-compatible
- `<tuple>`-free

One stylistic note: I prefer to name my parameter packs with plurals, so, singular `auto I` but plural `auto... Is`. That's the logic behind my renaming above.

Comment: About the `decltype(auto)`, I took the code straight from cppreference.com is the use there bogus too? Or is it specific to my code?

Comment: @tom about the `decltype(auto)`: Hmm, looks like it's non-bogus specifically because your `return` statement returns a prvalue, so `decltype(auto)` is actually [equivalent to `auto`](https://wandbox.org/permlink/P1kzTNP061AElCi7) in this case. But I still strongly recommend that you *never* use `decltype(auto)` in C++ until you can explain [the behavior of this little snippet.](https://wandbox.org/permlink/XBHV0YkfKcWU5XiF)  (Which, in practice, means: never use it, ever. ;))  — P.S. I adjusted the cppreference page. ;)

Comment: @Quuxplusone, or one can grab Effective Modern C++ :) I got a little bit confused about your comment on `decltype(auto)`, but now I see that it applies only to your code.

Comment: @Incomputable: I'm sure we're both being too vague. :) When I said "your return statement returns a prvalue, so `decltype(auto)` is actually equivalent to `auto` in this case", I was talking about Tom's code i.e. cppreference's code, and the first Wandbox link was an example demonstrating that concept in isolation. The word "this" in "this little snippet" was indeed intended to refer to the second Wandbox link itself.